# Setup a grafana for API tracking, CPU monitoring and health check

Tags: node.js, reactjs, prometheus, grafana

I have my backend in node js and frontend is in React js. Now I want to capture the number of requests per sec coming for individual API's like products API etc. Grafana is setup for this Node js server but does not have tracking at API level.
How can I implement this?